# How to draw a touch straight line in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touch, line

I'm trying to create a drawing tool set for the iPad and so far I've done the square, but I'm not sure how I would go about coding a **straight line**? Here's the code for my finished square, maybe it'll be a help. I would like to know how to code a straight line. After that, what if I wanted to draw circles as well? What in this code would I need to change?

Here's the code:

JavaScript (Square/Rectangle)

```
// "Draw Rectangle" Button
function rect(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasSignature'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), rect = {}, drag = false;

function init() {
  canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, false);
}


function touchHandler(event) {
  if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) { //one finger touche
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];

    if (event.type == "touchstart") {
      rect.startX = touch.pageX;
      rect.startY = touch.pageY;
      drag = true;
    } else if (event.type == "touchmove") {
      if (drag) {
        rect.w = touch.pageX - rect.startX;
        rect.h = touch.pageY - rect.startY ;
        draw();
      }
    } else if (event.type == "touchend" || event.type == "touchcancel") {
      drag = false;
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);


  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);



  ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
}

init();
}
```

Comment: Most of that code is just determining WHERE to draw the rectangle. There's only one line that actually draws it. Find that line and replace it with something else, like with a different method of the same class or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just substitute this:

```
ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

with something like this:

```
ctx.fillLine(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);

ctx.clearLine(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

this is of course not 100% valid code, but the concept should work and you'll get the point

Comment: Wait, do I change the rect.startX, etc to line.startX, etc as well?